# Find the closest number in a list of numbers

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have a list of constant numbers. I need to find the closest number to x in the list of the numbers. Any ideas on how to implement this algorithm?

Comment: Don't forget to consider the unusual cases. (1) what if there is no closest number? and (2) what if there are two different closest numbers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, you cannot do this faster than `O(N)` because you have to check all numbers to be sure you have the closest one. That said, why not use a simple variation on finding the minimum, looking for the one with the minimum absolute difference with *x*?

If you can say the list is ordered from the beginning (and it allows random-access, like an array), then a better approach is to use a binary search. When you end the search at index *i* (without finding *x*), just pick the best out of that element and its neighbors.

Comment: You can beat O(N) if your search space is sorted.

Comment: Yeah, using binary search tree logic should let you do it in O(log n).

Comment: Or an interpolation search, O(log log n) average

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but can't you just make a list of absolute numbers abs(yourNum - needle), pop it onto an array, then sort? The first index should be the closest?

Comment: @mardala that's O(N log N) because of the sorting.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose that the array is unordered. In ordered it can be faster

I think that the simpliest and the fastest method is using linear algorithm for finding minimum or maximum but instead of comparing values you will compare absolute value of difference between this and needle.

In the C++ ( I can't C# but it will be similar ) can code look like this:

```
// array of numbers is haystack
// length is length of array
// needle is number which you are looking for ( or compare with )

int closest = haystack[0];
for ( int i = 0; i < length; ++i ) {
  if ( abs( haystack[ i ] - needle ) < abs( closest - needle ) ) closest = haystack[i];
}
return closest;
```

Comment: Is "needle" some special nomenclature I'm not aware of?

Comment: "needle in the haystack" :D

Comment: "needle" and "haystack" are expressions which are often used with searching algorithms.

Comment: Although we often use the expression "needle in a haystack" when we're not expecting to have any luck finding the needle!

Answer (score 3):

In general people on this site won't do your homework for you.  Since you didn't post code I won't post code either.  However, here's one possible approach.

Loop through the list, subtracting the number in the list from x.  Take the absolute value of this difference and compare it to the best previous result you've gotten and, if the current difference is less than the best previous result, save the current number from the list.  At the end of the loop you'll have your answer.

Comment: The OP did use the `homework` tag. He is not trying to pull a fast one on you.

Answer (score 1):

```
private int? FindClosest(IEnumerable<int> numbers, int x)
{
    return
        (from number in numbers
        let difference = Math.Abs(number - x)
        orderby difference, Math.Abs(number), number descending
        select (int?) number)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Null means there was no closest number. If there are two numbers with the same difference, it will choose the one closest to zero. If two numbers are the same distance from zero, the positive number will be chosen.

**Edit in response to Eric's comment:**

Here is a version which has the same semantics, but uses the `Min` operator. It requires an implementation of `IComparable<>` so we can use `Min` while preserving the number that goes with each distance. I also made it an extension method for ease-of-use:

```
public static int? FindClosestTo(this IEnumerable<int> numbers, int targetNumber)
{
    var minimumDistance = numbers
        .Select(number => new NumberDistance(targetNumber, number))
        .Min();

    return minimumDistance == null ? (int?) null : minimumDistance.Number;
}

private class NumberDistance : IComparable<NumberDistance>
{
    internal NumberDistance(int targetNumber, int number)
    {
        this.Number = number;
        this.Distance = Math.Abs(targetNumber - number);
    }

    internal int Number { get; private set; }

    internal int Distance { get; private set; }

    public int CompareTo(NumberDistance other)
    {
        var comparison = this.Distance.CompareTo(other.Distance);

        if(comparison == 0)
        {
            // When they have the same distance, pick the number closest to zero
            comparison = Math.Abs(this.Number).CompareTo(Math.Abs(other.Number));

            if(comparison == 0)
            {
                // When they are the same distance from zero, pick the positive number
                comparison = this.Number.CompareTo(other.Number);
            }
        }

        return comparison;
    }
}
```

Comment: A charming use of LINQ. However, I note that this is O(n lg n) in time and O(n) in extra space. You can do it in O(n) time and O(1) space if you use the Min sequence operator rather than sorting.

Comment: Also, you still haven't fully disambiguated the statement of the problem. What if there are two numbers with the same difference and both of them are equally close to zero?

Comment: Good point. I ordered by `number descending` to ensure the positive number will be chosen (in the absence of a behavioral requirement, that's the most reasonable decision). I will work on the `Min` solution. Thanks for your feedback Eric!

Comment: Neat. Minor typo: numbers.Select(number => new NumberDistance(x, number) should be numbers.Select(number => new NumberDistance(targetNumber, number) shouldn't it?

Comment: @JohnKaster: You are correct. Feel free to edit, otherwise I will.

Comment: @BryanWatts just did, thanks. Wanted to make sure I didn't step on your toes. :)

Comment: @JohnKaster: Saw your edit was rejected - I made it myself. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx):
[Blog post on finding closest number](http://eli-shalom.blogspot.com/2009/11/easy-wins-optimizations-sorted-list.html)
If the complexity you're looking for counts only the searching the complexity is *O(log(n))*. The list building will cost *O(n*log(n))*

If you're going to insert item to the list much more times than you're going to query it for the closest number then the best choice is to use [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) and use naive algorithm to query it for the closest number. Each search will cost *O(n)* but time to insert will be reduced to *O(n)*.

General complexity: If the collection has *n* numbers and searched *q* times -
*List*: `O(n+q*n)`
*Sorted List*: `O(n*log(n)+q*log(n))`

Meaning, from some *q* the sorted list will provide better complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Being lazy I have not check this but shouldn't this work

```
private int FindClosest(IEnumerable<int> numbers, int x)
{
    return
        numbers.Aggregate((r,n) => Math.Abs(r-x) > Math.Abs(n-x) ? n
                                 : Math.Abs(r-x) < Math.Abs(n-x) ? r
                                 : r < x ? n : r);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haskell:

```
import Data.List (minimumBy)
import Data.Ord (comparing)

findClosest :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> [a] -> Maybe a
findClosest _ [] = Nothing
findClosest n xs = Just $ minimumBy (comparing $ abs . (+ n)) xs
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                Performance wise custom code will be more use full. 

                List<int> results;
                int targetNumber = 0;
                int nearestValue=0;
                if (results.Any(ab => ab == targetNumber ))
                {
                    nearestValue= results.FirstOrDefault<int>(i => i == targetNumber );
                }
                else
                {
                    int greaterThanTarget = 0;
                    int lessThanTarget = 0;
                    if (results.Any(ab => ab > targetNumber ))
                    {
                        greaterThanTarget = results.Where<int>(i => i > targetNumber ).Min();
                    }
                    if (results.Any(ab => ab < targetNumber ))
                    {
                        lessThanTarget = results.Where<int>(i => i < targetNumber ).Max();
                    }

                    if (lessThanTarget == 0 )
                    {
                        nearestValue= greaterThanTarget;
                    }
                    else if (greaterThanTarget == 0)
                    {
                        nearestValue= lessThanTarget;
                    }
                    else if (targetNumber - lessThanTarget < greaterThanTarget - targetNumber )
                    {
                        nearestValue= lessThanTarget;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            nearestValue= greaterThanTarget;
                    }
                }
```