# Retrieving 2 closest numbers among 3

Tags: sorting, language-agnostic, numbers

I'm looking for an algorithm to retrieve the two closest out of 3. I don't have any variable to get close to, just the three of this. For example, if i have 31, 52 and 84, i'd like the function to return 31 and 52.

I've tried some methods with array sorting, but fact is the three numbers are variables (X, Y and Z). When I sort my [X, Y, Z] array, i lose the order of vars.

I'm sure there's a very simple solution, i'm feeling quite silly right now... This is actually a MAXScript project so I'd like to avoid specific language functions, but any kind of information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does sorting have to do with this problem at all?

Comment: Duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988937/find-the-closest-number-in-a-list-of-numbers)

Comment: @Chris: That's a different problem with a different solution. This is finding the *two* closest numbers amount a set of given numbers. The other question is finding the *one* closest number in a set to a single given number.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz aha my mistake, I looked at the first answer in terms of algorithm specifics of finding out the closest between two numbers. And misread that only one is passed in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call the three numbers A, B, and C.

Compute three variables:

```
AB = (A - B)^2
BC = (B - C)^2
CA = (C - A)^2
```

Then compare AB, BC, and CA. If AB is smallest, output A and B. If BC is smallest, output B and C. If CA is smallest, output C and A.

If you want to make it a bit more elegant, create a structure that consists of three numbers and create three such structures as follows:

```
S1 = (A-B)^2, A, B
S2 = (B-C)^2, B, C
S3 = (C-A)^2, C, A
```

Then sort S1,S2,S3 based on the first number. For the entry that sorts first, output its second two numbers.

Comment: Actually, you could go with just `abs(A - B)` etc. :)

Comment: The way with sorting is obviously less efficient: you need O(n^2 log (n^2)) = O(n^2 log n) for it, while for simple finding a maximum just O(n^2) (here n is number of variables).

Comment: @Vlad Make a call into the library to call code that will likely have an unpredictable branch? Or make a macro? Or an if/negate with, again, an unpredictable branch. Yuck. A single multiplication is much nicer. (As for the complexity argument for sorting, if `n` is fixed at 3, it doesn't matter. But of course you're right that we only need to find the minimum.)

Comment: there is a possibility to calculate `abs` without branching with some bit tricks: http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerAbs

Comment: @Vlad: That seems like a lot of unneeded complexity for such a simple problem. But I suppose you can argue that your compiler may well have an inlined, optimized `abs` operation too.

Comment: (1) indeed `abs` implementation must be optimized by compiler, not by the developer; (2) multiplication seems to be unnecessary complication for me, while being a neat trick given that `abs` is slower.

Answer (score 3):

For just 3 variables, you need to compare the distances between them and choose the closest two (see David's answer). For `n` variables, you can do this trick:

1. sort the values (`O(n log n)`)
2. go through the sorted list and find the smallest difference between the adjacent variables (`O(n)`)
3. result is the pair of variables with the smallest difference

Comment: This is a nice approach. It's simple and efficient. And it doesn't require any fancy extra work to return the desired values.

Comment: @David: thanks for your evaluation! Anyway, my answer is just an enhancement for the imaginary case of `n` variables.

Comment: True, but even for just three variables, it's simpler to explain.